# Find the relative extrema of $f|_S$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

$$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\ (x,y) \rightarrow x^2 +y^2\\ S=\{(x,2) \ |\ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

I tried using Lagrange multipliers. 
I started by deriving the equation $x^2+y^2$ to get $f: 2x+2y$. Then I had $g(x,y)= (x,2)$ and derived it to get $g(x,y)= (1,0)$. I then set up the following equations:

$2x+2y= \lambda (1,0)$

$2x= \lambda $

$2y= 0$

Then I don't know what to do. Am I doing something wrong? Is my approach correct? How do I find the relative extrema from doing this since I only know $\lambda = 2x$?

Comment: You set it up wrongly. The given constraint is $y=2$. So let $g(x,y)=g(y)=y$. You should obtain $2x=0$, $2y=\lambda$, and $y=2$.

Comment: I got the value $f(0,2)=(0)^2+(2)^2=4$. How do I know if the value is a max or min?

Comment: It should be clear that it is a minimum since the function is a sum of positive terms.